# How can I soar like an eagle (in the Icarus Factor skill game)?

Tags: trials-evolution

My best distance in Icarus Factor to date is just over 100m, but some people on my friends list have made it well past the 300m mark. Does anyone have any tips on going the distance? Is there a specific method for flapping that works best?

Comment: Seems like it's more about the launch angle and launch you get, but maybe there is something to flapping. Looking forward to see if anyone knows.

Comment: I managed 200m yesterday, but I would still welcome tips for going farther yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My highest so far is 451.731m! This is what I find helps—it might be different for you:

When you start, reverse all the way back to the pipe, then hold the left stick diagonal left/down and pull full throttle. As your front wheel is off the ledge, press Y and flap your wings!

Answer (score 2):

After quite a bit of practice, my best attempt is now 476m, so I feel like I have a bit more of a handle on this skill game.

To begin with, I hold the left stick all the way to the right and begin with about 50% throttle. As I approach the ramp I increase this to 100% making sure to **not let the front of the bike come off the ground**. After hitting the ramp, hit Y to **bail out slightly before the apex of the jump**. Start flapping right away. The best method I've found is to leave your right thumb on Y and move your left thumb so that it can hit X, then **alternate X and Y as quickly as possible**. From watching the leaderboards, it looks like some people adjust their flight using the left thumbstick while in the air, but I didn't have much luck with that.

Happy flapping!

Answer (score 1):

Holding the left stick up and right helps maintain great flight speed, I tested it several times and I've come to find that your character actually flaps more if you hit x and y simultaneously and you do fly farther!

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is reverse back to the pipe then go about 60% throttle, then when you go past the barrier in the background go 100% throttle then bailout. Use your index finger and middle finger to flap then hold the left stick right diagonal upwards.

I've gotten up to 583m this way.

Answer (score 0):

Follow all the tips above. Hit X and Y at the same time. Adjust your rider in flight to try and keep him upright